# smtp error on vps hosting when sending email

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, phpmailer, vps

I installed the SMTP module (with the phpmailer). I can get it to work on Gmail and it sends mail fine. But when I try to set it up on my hosting company's server I get this error.

> 2015-06-29 13:41:52   SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-server.safensahookup.com
>   ESMTP Exim 4.85 #2 Mon, 29 Jun 2015 13:41:52 +0000
>       220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited,
>       220 and/or bulk e-mail. 2015-06-29 13:41:52   CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO 173.214.189.92 2015-06-29 13:41:52   SERVER -> CLIENT:
>   250-server.safensahookup.com Hello server.safensahookup.com
>   [173.214.189.91]
>       250-SIZE 52428800
>       250-8BITMIME
>       250-PIPELINING
>       250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
>       250-STARTTLS
>       250 HELP 2015-06-29 13:41:52   CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS 2015-06-29 13:41:52   SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 TLS go ahead 2015-06-29
>   13:41:53   CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO 173.214.189.92 2015-06-29 13:41:53
>   SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-server.safensahookup.com Hello
>   server.safensahookup.com [173.214.189.91]
>       250-SIZE 52428800
>       250-8BITMIME
>       250-PIPELINING
>       250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
>       250 HELP 2015-06-29 13:41:53   CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN 2015-06-29 13:41:53   SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6 2015-06-29
>   13:41:53   CLIENT -> SERVER: anVsaWVuZWVkczc4M0BnbWFpbC5jb20=
>   2015-06-29 13:41:53   SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6 2015-06-29
>   13:41:53   CLIENT -> SERVER: MDg5bm9tYW4= 2015-06-29 13:41:55   SERVER
>   -> CLIENT: 535 Incorrect authentication data 2015-06-29 13:41:55   SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535 Incorrect authentication data
>   2015-06-29 13:41:55   SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. 2015-06-29
>   13:41:55   CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 2015-06-29 13:41:55   SERVER ->
>   CLIENT: 221 server.safensahookup.com closing connection 2015-06-29
>   13:41:55   SMTP connect() failed.
>   https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Message
>   could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
>   https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: This is just a single line of log file, wrapped over many lines. It might be more readable if you put the line breaks in?

Comment: Just a hunch here, but "Incorrect authentication data", "Password command failed", "Error: Could not authenticate" might perhaps indicate that you've got your id and/or password wrong?

Comment: i did not use wrong userid and password, it was the ip table problem. i found it and solved it. thanks.